# How to relate a table properties with a features table

Tags: mysql

I'm making a mysql database and im facing a problem on the desing. im making a website that runs a real state company and im desingning the database i dont understand how can i make a property reference multiple features such as if the property has garage, wifi, , use of pool, cable, balcony etc. Can you give me advice on achieving this in not a dirty way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the design of your database, but normally the efficient way to achieve that is creating a second table with primary key (property_id, feature) so you can match the tables later in a very simple way.

Comment: u mean a many to many relationshipt between the two tables  which would create a third table where i match their ids?

Comment: Yes, it is the best option in this situations.